# Class Based Component or Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native and i am little confused , is there any rules that i have to follow when choosing what to use functional component or class based component since we can make a component in both way ?

Also React started supporting hooks at version 16.8, should i abandon classes together if it's new code base ?

Comment: It's a matter of tatse more than anything else

Comment: I think you will have smaller footprint when not extending `Component` in a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be major difference before React introduced Hooks. Basically functional component didn't have local state in the past. So people used to prefer class when local state is required. But with the advent of hooks, this is no longer the issue and thus you can go with any one you want.

You might like class if you have background with any other framework. For more details, have a look at this article by Dan Abramov here.
https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/